# Unserialization: naming and implementation

Tags: php, serialization

I have a bunch of objects that I need to be able to serialize in JSON, PHP, whatnot. I have stuff such as a JSONSerializer, and clearly have serialize() available. Now what I still need is object specific logic to turn the objects into something that can be fed to JSONSerializer or serialize(). Basically either a primitive type or an array containing only elements matching this condition.

Two questions:

1. How do you call this step before serialization? "arrayification"? I'm thinking of giving my objects a toArray() method. I also want them to implement some interface that specifies this method? Anyone a better idea then "Arrayable"?
2. How can I go best about unserialization? I could have a static newFromArray method in each object. Not fond of static code though. Any opinions on a factory that can construct objects of a given type from their "arrayification"?

Note: This needs to work with PHP 5.3.

Comment: you may want to take a look at this: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/pson

Using this you can convert php objects to json and back. It's written by Sebastian Bergman, the same guy who wrote PHPUnit

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting. I'll have a look at it even though for this project I cannot use PHP 5.4.

Comment: I in fact do not like the approach taken in PSON. The serialization needs to not contain any class names or non-public state. Furthermore I want to specify all the keys myself since these should also be independent of field names.

Comment: There is already something similar to `Arrayable` in the SPL `Iterator`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php. I don't know wheter it's useful to you.

Comment: Note: there is also the  a Serializable Interface which should replace the old `__sleep` & `__wakeup` functionality http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php

Comment: I am familiar with the Serializable interface and am implementing it already. It however does not fit some of my usescases. It violates the same demands as PSON.

Comment: Please improve your title so that it describes the problem rather than being a single word that says basically nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Symfony Serializer Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) provides one answer to both questions. It calls the step from object to array "normalization" and the reverse "denormalization".

For construction of "deserializers" or "denormalizers", I have found creating an abstract factory very useful. It solves the construction problem, and can isolate the user from even knowing which exact deserializer they are using. An example of this is [this deserializer factory](https://github.com/wmde/Ask/blob/master/src/Ask/DeserializerFactory.php#L24) which is based on the [Serialization component](https://github.com/wmde/Serialization).